# Google Drive API - Files and Permissions - 403 Rate Limit Exceeded

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I use a google service account to access a domain's users and their files. Our current API usage is way below the daily allotted quota and doesn't even cross 50% most of the time and I have implemented exponential back off as well.

Even though, at times, I receive the following exception with this service account.

{
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "rateLimitExceeded",
    "message": "Rate Limit Exceeded"
}

This exception is more pronounced for a period of few hours daily whereas the developers console around the same time indicates that we didn't even cross 10% of the daily quota at that time.

This exception is seen for drive API methods such as files.list, files.get, permissions.list, and about.get.

Google Drive SDK [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/) doesn't seem to provide information about API Rate Limits and Quotas. Google folks! Are there any other internal limits other than the daily limit and per user limit?

P.S: I know that there are certain limits on number of uploads, number of downloads, and number of permission insert operations. But I receive this exception for the aforementioned methods and I am not aware of any limits on these methods.

Comment: Drive API has only per user rate limit and quota per day. Did you implement exponential back off for your application? If you are sending too many requests at a time, it will result in rate limit error. check this link https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors

Comment: @SGC, As mentioned in the post, I have implemented exponential backoff in my code. The link just gives an example on how to implement exponential backoff. There is no mention of rate limit under 'Errors and suggested actions'.

Comment: See my answer for a similar question, you may be experiencing the same issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33679022/google-drive-user-rate-limit-exceeded-different-users-and-different-gae-projects