# Google Drive User Rate Limit Exceeded different users and different GAE projects

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

Is there any one having problems with Google Drive API?

We are getting this error:

```
error: {,…}
code: 403
errors: [{domain: "usageLimits", reason: "userRateLimitExceeded", message: "User Rate Limit Exceeded"}]
0: {domain: "usageLimits", reason: "userRateLimitExceeded", message: "User Rate Limit Exceeded"}
message: "User Rate Limit Exceeded"
```

on different API projects (different GAE Projects) and with different user names, network, etc..

It seems a general issue.

See here the logs from the last 7 days:
[Log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdme4.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that you supply the `userIp` (or `quotaUser`) parameter on each API request made by your server-side code, as documented in the ["Standard Query Parameters"](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/query-parameters) section of the Drive API reference.

Otherwise, it is possible that all of your API requests are being counted against a single user (since they will all be coming from the same IP address) and therefore it wouldn't be surprising if you start running into request rate limitations.