# Is it possible to increase the Google Sheets API quota limit beyond 2500 per account and 500 per user?

Tags: api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, quota

**The problem:** Running into Google Sheets API read/write quota limits. Specifically, the *read/write requests per 100 seconds* and *read/write requests per 100 seconds per user* quotas.

**Some background:**
For the past few months I've been developing a web app for students and staff in our school district which uses a Google spreadsheet as the database. Each school in our district was assigned a different Google spreadsheet, and a service account was created to make read and write calls to these spreadsheets on behalf of the web app.

We started with one school of approximately 1000 students, but it has now expanded to two other schools with a total user load of around 4000. Due to the nature of a school day schedule, we started hitting our quota limit (per 100 sec & per 100 sec per user) since almost everyone uses the app at the same time.

I found the [usage limits](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits) guide for the Google sheets API, and as per the instructions I created a billing account, and linked the associated service account project to it. I then went to the quotas section in the developers console and applied for a higher quota. This involved filling out a Google form which asked "How much quota do you need? Express in number of API queries per day." Again, *queries per day* is not the problem, rather it's the number of queries per 100 seconds and per user (service account). After a couple of weeks our limit was increased to 2500 read/write requests per 100 seconds and 500 read/write requests per 100 seconds per user. The billing account was not charged, and after a little searching, I realized this was a free increase. This bump in our quota limit helped, but it's still going to be an issue because our district wants to add more schools in the future.

**Here's what I need to know:**

**1) [ESSENTIAL QUESTION] Does Google have an upper limit or maximum to the number of read/write requests a single service account/user/IP can make within the 100 second time frame, and if so what is it?**

**2)** If it is possible to go beyond our current quota limit (2500/500), is there another way of requesting/applying for the increase. Once again we have a billing account established for the project and are willing to pay for the service.

I've been pulling (what's left of) my hair out trying to find definitive answers to my questions. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45225734/how-to-increase-google-sheets-v4-api-quota-limitations) came close to what I was looking for, and I even did some of the things the OP suggested, but I just need a direct answer to my "essential" question.

**Couple more things.**
I understand that Google Charts Visualization doesn't have a quota limitation, and I'd consider using it however, for privacy reasons I can't have the spreadsheet keys exposed in plain javascript. Are there other options here?
Also, one might suggest creating multiple service accounts, but I'd rather avoid this if possible.

Thank you for your help. I'm very much a novice and I greatly appreciate your time and expertise.

Comment: Backlog and cache requests and make batch requests slowly?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question but is there a compelling reason to use Google Sheets instead of a real database?

Comment: @nijave Thanks for responding. There's a couple a reasons; first being that various tech-phobic users (some teachers and school admin) need to access the spreadsheet and feel more comfortable with Google sheets. The second reason is that there numerous formulas running on the spreadsheets for which I have no clue how to create equivalent server-side database scripts for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1) [ESSENTIAL QUESTION] Does Google have an upper limit or maximum to the number of read/write requests a single service account/user/IP can make within the 100 second time frame, and if so what is it?

- ***The provided [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits) only stated that *Google Sheets API has a limit of 500 requests per 100 seconds per project, and 100 requests per 100 seconds per user.* Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33727685/5832311) for additional information.***

2) If it is possible to go beyond our current quota limit (2500/500), is there another way of requesting/applying for the increase. Once again we have a billing account established for the project and are willing to pay for the service.

- ***AFAIK, you can request for a higher quota limit and the Google Engineers may grant the request as long as you are making a reasonable request.***

Also, you may check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45227916/5832311) for additional tips:

> 1. You can use [spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) to read the entire spreadsheet in a single call, rather than 1 call per request.  Alternately, you
>      can use [spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet) to read multiple different
>      ranges in a single call, if all you need are the values.
> 2. The Drive API offers "[push notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push)", so you can get notified when changes occur and react to those, instead of polling for
>      them.  The latency of the notifications is a little on the slow side,
>      but it gets the job done.