# Is there a cost to change Google Sheets API quotas?

Tags: google-sheets-api

When I try to change Google Sheets API quotas (300 per minute to 600), it says "You can't request more quota because your project is not linked to a billing account."

If I set my billing account, is there a cost to change Google Sheets API quotas?

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3ST2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a [help article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#:~:text=Request%20changes%20to%20quota%20from,if%20you%20use%20more%20resources.) by Google:

> There is no charge for requesting a quota increase. Your costs increase only if you use more resources.

So by going from that, you should not be charged if you increase your quota but instead if the number of requests to the server goes past the original quota. You will be charged by the number of requests to the server so if you hit 301 read requests per minute then you will be charged accordingly, but not the same as hitting 600 requests per minute. If you stay below the 300 read requests per minute quota then it appears that you will not be charged.

Comment: After that, I found a post about this subject.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52266726/is-it-possible-to-increase-the-google-sheets-api-quota-limit-beyond-2500-per-acc

In this post, he says it was free even when it increased to 2500 per 100 seconds.
So I think there isn't a cost to change Google Sheets API quotas, at least before 2500.(But he needed to set a billing account)